# graph_tool: access vertex/edge property faster

Tags: python, graph-algorithm, graph-tool

I'd like to speed up the vertex/edge property access process.

For vertex property access, I find one way to optimize however for edge property access, it is not so trivial to me.

The idea for vertex property is to modify the internal array (`a` property) directly.

For example

```
vfilt = g.new_vertex_property('bool')
for i in range(9999): 
    vfilt.a[int(i % n)] = random.randint(0, 1)
```

(note `vfilt.a` not `vfilt`)

instead of using:

```
vfilt = g.new_vertex_property('bool')
for i in range(9999): 
    vfilt[int(i % n)] = random.randint(0, 1)
```

however, for edge, I'm not sure about the mapping between edge and its internal index in the property array.

My question is:

- how to optimize edge property access?
- is there other ways to optimize vertex property?

Answer (score 1):

How about

```
for e in g.edges():
    vfilt[e] = random.randint(0, 1)
```

Similarly, for vertices:

```
for v in g.vertices():
    vfilt[v] = random.randint(0, 1)
```